# React how to show one element at a time in an array automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of items, let's say

```
const item = ['ford','porche','ferrari']
```

What I would like to do is show each item in the array one at  a time on the screen, content changing automatically continuosly(with some time interval).

So senario is show ford first, then porche(ford disappears) and ferrari(porche disappears), then back to ford. Repeat this sequence infinitely until user closes.

I know should use setInterval to start with,  but  not sure the rest.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a state or global variable such as currentIndex = 0;
and the function would go like

```
() => {
setTimeout(() => {
  let index = currentIndex;

  if(currentItem = items.length -1){
    index = 0;
  }
  this.setState({
    currentItem = items[index]
  })
  currentIndex++;
})
}
```

Comment: Thanks! got the idea! I just have to turn setTimeout to setInterval right?